# Get a list of All Facebook pages with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph APIs for getting FB pages. I have more then 100 FB pages. But my API return only 25 page in list.  Here is my code

```
       try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            $response = $this->fb->get('me/accounts', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            //redirect('login');

        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            //redirect('login');

        }
```

How to get all 100 pages list..?

Comment: Go read the documentation on basic API usage, regarding the `limit` parameter and pagination ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add limit=100 to your api call and if you have more than that you need to recursively call the api with the paging link:-

"paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "ODc4MzY2NTY1NjU0Mjg3",
      "after": "MzQzNTE0NDIyMzYzMzcy"